# JodaDateTime Serializer with Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, serialization, jodatime

I'm using Spring 4 and Joda Datetime.
I have custom serializer, and I have annotate domain field with my serializer.

```
@JsonSerialize(using=ISODateTimeSerializer.class)
private DateTime date;
```

And that is working fine.

Now, I have need to use my services inside serializer. That means that I must register my serializer with Spring configuration. I tried a couple of different approaches, but none of them worked and injected service is always null.

I have ApplicationConfiguration with couple of conf classes and I read that I must make ObjectMapper and register it. I was not able to find guide how to do it, do you know how that should be accomplished?

UPDATE 1

My Serializer

```
public class ISODateTimeSerializer extends JsonSerializer<DateTime> {

@Inject
private SecurityUtils securityUtils;

    private static DateTimeFormatter formatter =
            DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");


    @Override
    public void serialize(DateTime value, JsonGenerator generator,
                          SerializerProvider arg2)
            throws IOException {

        UserSecurityWrapper user = securityUtils.getCurrentUser();      
        //... some logic


        generator.writeString(formatter.withZone(dateTimeZone).print(value));
    }

}
```

My test configuration

```
@Configuration
public class ObjectMappingConfiguration {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ObjectMappingConfiguration.class);

@Bean
public String registerOM() {
       ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
       SimpleModule testModule = new SimpleModule("MyModule", new Version(1, 0, 0, null));
       testModule.addSerializer(new ISODateTimeSerializer()); 
       mapper.registerModule(testModule);
       return "OK";
    }
}
```

Thanks

**UPDATE 2**
I tried this, and still no success.

```
@Configuration
public class ObjectMappingConfiguration {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ObjectMappingConfiguration.class);

    @Bean
    public Module apiJodaModule() {
        return new ApiJodaModule();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    private static class ApiJodaModule extends SimpleModule {
        public ApiJodaModule() {
            addDeserializer(DateTime.class, new ISODateTimeDeserializer());
            addSerializer(DateTime.class, new ISODateTimeSerializer());
        }
    }

}




public class ISODateTimeSerializer extends StdScalarSerializer<DateTime> {

    private static DateTimeFormatter formatter =
            DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");

    @Inject
    private SecurityUtils securityUtils;

    public ISODateTimeSerializer() {
        super(DateTime.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(DateTime value, JsonGenerator generator,
                          SerializerProvider arg2)
            throws IOException {

        UserSecurityWrapper user = securityUtils.getCurrentUser();
        //.....


        generator.writeString(formatter.withZone(dateTimeZone).print(value));
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Take a look at this page in the Jackson docs](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers) about how to add a custom serializer to an ObjectMapper instance.

If you are using Spring XML, which might make calling arbitrary methods on an ObjectMapper hard, take a look at creating a Spring FactoryBean.

Assuming you are using Spring MVC and you want to modify the ObjectMapper used by the MVC framework, you'll have to look [at modifying the HttpMessageConverter used for Jackson](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-customize).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code seems to be that you are handling Serializer/Deserializer object instantiation yourself (using new), instead of delegating that responsibility to Spring.

You could add a @Component annotation to ISODateTimeSerializer (and with the assumption that compoment scan is enabled), and use @Autowired for it inside ObjectMappingConfiguration.